# Problema ao utilizar Dialog Prime Faces

Tags: java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Boa noite,
Estou desenvolvendo um CRUD simples utilizando JSF,mas estou com problemas ao utilizar as funções do Prime Faces.
Quero fazer as inserções, alterações e exclusões através de `Dialogs`...mas até o agora não consegui utilizar as funções...o dialog não aparece na tela.
aparentemente os métodos do Bean não estão funcionando.
Eu consigo acessar os métodos do Bean e aparentemente consegui mapear o `id` do `form` que está dentro do `dialog`, no atributo `update`.Porém não consegui acessar o `dialog` usando `oncomplete="dialogGerLivro.show()"`

Classe Bean

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ListaController implements Serializable {

@Inject
private ListaDAO dao;
private Lista lista;

public Lista getLista() {
    if (lista == null) {
        lista = new Lista();
    }
    return lista;
}

public void setLista(Lista lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
}

public void adicionar() {
    lista = new Lista();
}
```

Página .xhtml

```
 <h:form id="formLista">

        <p:commandButton value="Adicionar Lista" actionListener="#{listaController.adicionar()}" update=":formLista:formDados:painelDadosLista" oncomplete="dialogGerLivro.show()"/>

      //DataTable

        <p:dialog header="Gerencia de Livro" widgetVar="dialogGerLivro">
            <h:form id="formDados">
                <h:panelGrid  id="painelDadosLista" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">

                    <h:outputLabel for="titulo" value="Título:" />
                    <h:inputText id="titulo" value="#{listaController.lista.titulo}"/>


                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 3):

A partir da versão 4.1 do Primefaces é necessário que você use a seguinte sintaxe: `PF('widgetVar').show()`, onde `widgetVar` é o nome do dialog que você quer exibir.